# can the value of css counter(pages) be assigned to a variable in php

Tags: php, css, pdf, printing

I am printing a dynamic HTML page into pdf using php. I'd like to move a certain "" element from the first page to the last page during printing. I'm using the following css:

```
.last-page {
                page: last_page;
                page-break-before: always; 
            }
```

and in php I'm adding:

```
<div class='last-page'></div>
```

before the  element that I want to move to the last page.

I'd like to know the number of pages, so I can add the  that number of times. Is there a way I can get the value of css counter(pages) to make a loop or any other way to know how many pages will be in the printed page?

Thanks